# Problem with HTML2Canvas losing background image

Tags: javascript, css, html2canvas

I have some JavaScript to capture an element on a page to a canvas using HTML2CANVAS.  In the code this is "elementToCapture" and is a container on the main HTML page consisting of a JPG image used as a background image (a border with a central field of very light colored graphic.) The other elements in the element are divs with text and a table.  These overlay the background and the background color of the overlay items is  set with background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0) which produces a completely transparent overlay and the back gound shows though.  Using the code snippet  below I am only able to capture the overlay text and table elements to the canvas even though the debugger shows that the image element is the first child in the elementToCapture. Can't figure out why I lose the graphic element on the canvas produced.  The canvas is displayed using the toDataURL as a src reference.  This part of the code is not included.

```
html2canvas(elementToCapture, {
       width: elementToCapture.scrollWidth,
       height: 1.2*elementToCapture.scrollHeight
           }).then(function(canvas) {
      imageDataUrl = canvas.toDataURL('imgage/png');
```

Comment: Have  you used your browser devtools inspect facility to check for errors on the console? Where did the image come from? Are you getting a CORS error for example?

Comment: The image is from a library on the same server that hosts the html.  All displayed perfectly in the HTML page.   Problem is with the HTML2Canvas.  Problem persists if the copied entity is only a single image without any of the overlays.  In this case all is blank in the canvas whereas the HTML shows the image.

Comment: Can you create the simplest possible example that demonstrates the problem?